# How to open and read a character device as binary file?

Tags: devices, c, size, open-files, character-device

I'm working with USB and I want to read the content of usb device descriptor in /dev/bus/usb/00x/00y - it is a character device.

I used fopen to open it as a binary file with "rb" parameter. But when I do the seek and tell to get file size, it returned 0 bytes in size. Is there a way to read it as a binary file?

```
void ReadUsbDeviceDescriptor( const char* path )
{
    FILE* usb_fd = NULL;
    size_t lSize = 0;

    if ( path != NULL )
    {
        usb_fd = fopen ( path, "rb");
        if ( usb_fd != NULL )
        {
            fseek( usb_fd , 0 , SEEK_END );
            lSize = ftell (usb_fd);
            rewind( usb_fd );

            printf("File: %s - Size: %lu bytes\n", path, lSize);

            fclose( usb_fd );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Could not open file %s\n", path );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

```
File: /dev/bus/usb/001/001 - Size: 0 bytes
```

Comment: As it's not a regular file, the `fseek` is likely failing, if you check the resultcode ?

Comment: @steve You're right, ```fseek```  failed. As @RalfFriedl said below, I can use ```fread``` to read byte one by one to the end of the file, then get the length. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As steve mentioned, file size is rarely meaningful on a character device.

So the solution is simply open, read, be done. What is even the purpose of ftell here? If you want to allocate a buffer in advance, the answer is, you can't.

I suggest you try what your program does with `/dev/tty`. Maybe first think what you expect would or should happen.

Another point is that on Unix systems, all files are binary, so mode `rb` is not necessary. On systems like Windows it makes a difference, but it's unlikely that there even exists a `/dev/usb` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can use ```fread``` to read byte one by one to get the length. It worked well. Thanks again!